# sql alchmeny: formating a SQL Query with table name and other variable names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, string-formatting

I have three coloumns in the following table:

```
col1, col2, col3
```

now, I have the following python code

```
    table = "#temp_table"
    col = 'col1'
    val = 'a'
    cursor.execute("""select "{}" from "{}" as a where "{}" ="{}"
""".format(col1,table,col1,val))
```

For reasons that are probably obvious to others, this does not work. How can I rewrite this to satisfy what I am trying to acomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will work if you change " -> ` :

```
    cursor.execute("""select `{}` from `{}` as a where `{}` =`{}`
""".format(col1,table,col1,val))
```